# Setting the navigation bar color in monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar

I am attempting to write an application with MonoTouch. I need to set the background color of the navigation bar. I'd like to set it to orange. This seems like an easy task, but I can't seem to get it to work. Currently, I'm doing the following in the AppDelegate.cs file:

```
this.window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
this.rootNavigationController = new UINavigationController();   

UIColor backgroundColor = new UIColor(74, 151, 223, 255);
this.rootNavigationController.NavigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;
```

However, the navigation bar color is still the default color. How do I set the background color of the navigation bar?

Comment: The following code won't do what you expect: `new UIColor(74, 151, 223, 255)` since the .ctor accepts `float`s, not bytes. Try using `UIColor.FromRGBA` if you want to use `byte`s to create your colors.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this on an ad-hoc basis as Rob described using the TintColor property:

```
this.rootNavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.Orange;
```

Alternatively, you can also set the TintColor for all UINavigationBars at once using the UIAppearance proxy in iOS 5. This is usually done somewhere near DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the AppDelegate:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.Orange;
```

You can check out the Apple doc for more detailed information and implementation restrictions:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Seems not all view in monotouch supports the TintColor property.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the TintColor and Translucent properties.